# Qt change tree widget arrow color via stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I haven't found any documentation on how to change the color of the QTreeWidgt it's arrow via stylesheets.

[image: QTreeWidget arrow]

When I set QPalette::WindowText in the QPalette the color of the little arrow will change, but I want to do it via stylesheets so my users can change the theme. I couldn't find anything on the internet about this.

[image]

Comment: several palette are predefined on QT generally, and you can define your palettes, so use them

Comment: @bruno I don't want to use palettes. I said "but I want to do it via stylesheets so my users can change the theme".

Comment: sorry I wanted to way stylesheet rather than palette ^

Comment: @bruno I don't get what you are trying to say. I'm already using stylesheets and I want to know how I can change the little arrow to a different color.

Comment: look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html#tree-branch-indicators

Comment: This does not seem to have any stylesheet options though

Comment: I think that you will have to modify the branch icon. [customizing tree view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different triangle image for this purpose

```
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings  {
    border-image: none;
    image: url(branch-open.png);
}
QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
    border-image: none;
    image: url(branch-closed.png);
}
```

https://forum.qt.io/topic/8034/changing-the-color-of-qtreeview-s-branches
and
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview